# Usage of Instruction* llvm::Instruction::user_back ( )

Tags: llvm

I am learning llvm now. I am confused with Instruction::user_back().

The docs said "user_back - Specialize the methods defined in Value, as we know that an instruction can only be used by other instructions. " But I still don't know what it returns.

I couldn't find more information about it. I guess for an instruction u, if u is in i->users(), u->user_back() will return i. When I tried to check my guess, I encountered with the following runtime error:

```
opt: /usr/local/include/llvm/IR/Value.h:144: UseT& llvm::Value::use_iterator_impl<UseT>::operator*() const [with UseT = llvm::Use]: Assertion `U && "Cannot dereference end iterator!"' failed.
```

My pass is like this:

```
for (auto &B : F) { 
    for (auto &I : B) {
         if (auto *target = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(&I)) {         
            for(auto it : target->users()){
              if (Instruction *I = dyn_cast<Instruction>(it)){
                  Instruction *temp = I->user_back();
                  errs() << "user_back"<< *temp <<"\n";
                  //Aborted (core dumped)             
                }       
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

My first question is whether I misunderstood the usage of Instruction* llvm::Instruction::user_back(), what's the correct meaning of it?

My second question is for an Instruction U, if U is in Instruction I->users(), is there a method to obtain whose user U is? In this case, is there a method for me to obtain I from U please? Could U->user_back() return I please?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of user_back is exactly backward.

Each Value V has a set of users -- other Values that use V.  So user_back is the last such user in the list.  You're getting the assert because your instruction u apparently doesn't have any users.  Check user_empty first.

You want the opposite relationship: given instruction U, find instructions used by U. To get that you have to iterate over U's operands.  Each operand O is a Use and O.get() will retrieve the Value used, which could be a Constant, Instruction or any kind of Value.  Since LLVM IR is in SSA there will be only once such Value for each operand.

In short, the answer to your second question is, "Iterate over U's operands and one of those will be I."